# JVM Implementing JRE

Tags: jvm, java

1. JVM is an implementation of JRE.  So every device which has JVM will contain JRE right?
2. JDK contains Set of classes and Libraries which support Development.  Does JRE contains the Same.  If so why they need the same since we already have our code converted to byte code?

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Check out the official Java SE documentation page that contains a very nice graphical illustration and explanations of what contains what. All items there are clickable: [Java Platform Standard Edition 7 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have number 1 a little backward. The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) contains a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), along with the standard java libraries and other things which allow Java byte-code programs to run.

The JDK Java Development Kit is like a superset of the JRE. It has all the things a JRE has, but adds things like a compiler and debugger to allow you to not only run Java byte-code, but create it from Java source files.

Comment: Im am not clear with the second one.My Question is Does JRE contains Classes and Libraries that JDK contains to Run Java Code.

Comment: Yes, it does. The JRE contains everything you need to run already compiled Java programs.